# Non optional property with custom setter Kotlin

Tags: java, android, properties, kotlin

I hope someone can help, I am writing moving from java to Kotlin and I want to have a property that it initialised in the init block, that has a custom setter but is non optional.

Here is my code below, however this has a warning that tag must be initialised

I would like to make it lateInit, but that means it has to be optional (which I don't want)

```
class SkiMarker(mapView: MapView, tag:Tag) : Marker(mapView){
var tag:Tag      <- ERROR here
    set(tag){
        this.tag = tag
        if(tag != null){
            this.mPosition = GeoPoint(tag.lat,tag.lon)
        }
    }


init {
    this.tag            = tag
    this.mPosition      = GeoPoint(tag.lat,tag.lon)
    val window          = MyInfoWindow(mapView,tag)
    this.infoWindow     = window
    window.subject.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe { it ->
        setIconForTracking(it)
    }
  } 
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that logic you only need to use a **backing field**:

```
class SkiMarker(mapView: MapView, tag:Tag) : Marker(mapView) {
    var tag: Tag = tag
        set(newTag){
            field = newTag  // `field` is a keyword
        }
}
```

Note that code like `set(newTag) {tag = newTag}` is equivalent to `setTag(newTag: Tag) { setTag(newTag) }` where it is actually calling the setter from within itself in a recursion.

Also, `tag` is never `null`, so `if(tag != null)` is meaningless.

Comment: Minor note, but it may be worth mentioning Kotlin convention is to use `value` and the setter parameter.